# Z buffer working in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, rasterizer, fragment-shader, buffers

After Z-Buffer Testing does the fragment shader run on the discarded fragments?
Does the Z-Test happen after the fragment shader runs?

Please, tell me the step by step events that occur in the Z-Test.

Also what is early Z-Test and how to achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When depth testing is enabled, the testing occurs after the fragment shader executes. The procedure is relatively simple (and spelled out pretty well [here](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test)):

- Get depth of fragment
- Test against depth buffer
- Discard if it fails

Early-z discard is when a rasterizer discards a fragment before a fragment shader runs because it's clear early on that it won't pass the depth test. However, the rasterizer can't safely do this if certain things happen (such as calling `discard()` or modifying the fragment depth in a fragment shader). This is a hardware optimization and isn't required to occur unless you force it with OpenGL 4.2 or with an extension.

There are things that can [prevent early-z discard from occurring](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Early_Fragment_Test#Limitations). To achieve it:

- Don't use `discard()` in a fragment shader
- Don't modify the depth of a fragment in a fragment shader
- Don't use alpha testing (deprecated)
- Make sure you have depth testing turned on
- Make sure you have a depth buffer